# How change direction in GridLayoutManager each even line?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have `layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 3)`

How to make each odd line direction from left to right and even line - from right to left

Look like:

```
0 -> 1 -> 2

5 <- 4 <- 3

6 -> 7 -> 8

etc...
```

What are some ideas guys?

Comment: Could you override the bind method in your adapter, so that it looks up data in the order: `0,1,2,5,4,3,6,...`. If you have 6n+4 items or 6n+5 items, you will need a dummy item layout to fill the blank spaces at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @AjahnCharles sorry not clear what you mean, please explain me

Comment: I posted a complete example below

Answer (score 1):

*DISCLAIMER: I'm on my phone so this is untested*

If you write your own `RecyclerView.Adapter`, you can override the bind method to lookup data "in the wrong order":

Pos0: Data0 -> Pos1: Data 1 -> Pos2: Data 2
Pos3: Data **5** -> Pos4: Data **4** -> Pos5: Data **3**
Pos6: Data 6 -> Pos7: Data 7 -> Pos8: Data 8
Pos9: *spacer* -> Pos10: *spacer* -> Pos11: Data **9**

I'm assuming you are passing some collection of data to your adapter; we also need the number of columns:

```
class SnakingAdapter(
    private val data: SomeCollection<SomeObject>, 
    private val cols: Int
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SomeViewHolder> { ... }
```

First let's handle the edge case where your RecyclerView ends on an incomplete even row. For example, if you have 10 data items (max index 9), I assume you want the last item on the right (not the left). We would do this by creating 2 "spacer" items in front of it:

```
private val twoRows = cols * 2 // left > right & right > left
private val remainder = data.count() % twoRows

// If last row is an odd row => no "spacers"
// If last row is complete => no "spacers"
private val needSpacers = remainder > cols
private val paddedCount = 
    if(needSpacers) (data.count() / twoRows + 1) * twoRows
    else data.count()
private val firstSpacerPosition = data.count() / cols * cols
private val spacerPositions = 
    if(needSpacers) List(paddedCount - data.count()) {  firstSpacerPosition + it }
    else emptyList<Int>()

override fun getItemCount(): Int = paddedCount

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int =
    if(spacerPositions.contains(position)) 2
    else 1

override onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = when(viewType) { 
    1 => // create a normal item view & ViewHolder
    2 => // create a "spacer" item view & ViewHolder
}
```

Next we need to bind the "wrong" data for even rows:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position Int) { 
    // If spacer, do nothing
    if(spacerPositions.contains(position)) return

    // If even row, flip the order of the data
    val twoRowPos = position % twoRows
    val rowTwomidpoint = cols / 2 + cols // TODO: extract as a field
    val altPosition = 
      if (twoRowPos >= cols) (position - 2 * (twoRowPos - rowTwoMidpoint)) // TODO: correct for odd cols; should fix for even cols
      else position

    val data = dataSource.get(altPosition)
    // bind data to view holder here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you looking to right to left layout then try this one.

Did you try to execute your code with `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` on API Level 17 ?

Comment: reread my question, i'm looking for only for GridLayoutManager lines, not for all app